# InTune Autopilot Primary User change

Tags: azure, mdm, hybrid, intune

How can I setup automation or settings to change most logged-in user,as primary user in Intune autopilot enrolled machines?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for could be done with the Graph APIs for AzureAD Sign-Ins and Intune.

But if your devices regularly have multiple users, best practice is to deploy the [shared multi-user device configuration profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/shared-user-device-settings-windows). Then the device is configured without a primary user, but still receives policy.